How to Bake Procedural Textures into Multiple Images for Large Meshes?
I have applied a procedural texture to a mesh with a very large number of faces. I want to bake this procedural texture into a texture image so that I can use the mesh in other software, like Unreal Engine, which does not support procedural textures directly.
Since there are so many faces, the pixel size of the image needs to be huge to ensure sufficient resolution in the baked texture. My idea is to associate multiple images as materials to cover the entire mesh, with each image having a normal pixel size (for example, 4096 x 4096 pixels).
To illustrate my point, I created a plane and applied a procedural texture to it. The plane has 9 faces, and I performed a Smart UV Project. My goal is to bake this procedural texture in such a way as to obtain:
Faces 1, 2, 3, 4: material_1 with bake_image_1
Faces 5, 6, 7, 8, 9: material_2 with bake_image_2

Initially, I would like to know how to do this manually, so that I can later automate the process with a Python script.
I am attaching the corresponding .blend file to this message.
Thank you in advance for your help!
Etienne

